# SELECT data from MySQL database INSERT to Oracle - is it possible?

Tags: mysql, oracle, interface, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-migration

I have two databases set up on the same computer. One MySQL and another Oracle.
I used Oracle SQL Developer to open local connections with them - standard for Oracle and using JDBC for MySQL connection.
Since I have them both opened I am wondering if there is any way to pass data between them. For example to create two exact same tables in each and then select some rows from one and pass to anohter?

I'll be gratefull for any advice. Thanks!

Comment: if you want see data and using in Oracle from MySQL , you can using DBLink, Also Oracle GoldenGate. But using same data in to two DB need using app for synchronism.

Answer (score 0):

Create a database link from your Oracle server to the MySQL server.

```
insert into my_oracle_table  
select * from my_mysql_table@dblinkname;
```

Please follow the below details and link.

-- Remote Username: scott

-- Remote Password: tiger

-- Private database link to a user in a remote database.

CREATE DATABASE LINK scott_remote CONNECT TO scott IDENTIFIED BY tiger USING 'remote_database';

-- Private database link to a user in a remote database, with full connection string.

CREATE DATABASE LINK scott_remote CONNECT TO scott IDENTIFIED BY tiger
USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server1.example.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=HRDEV1)))';

-- Public Database link.

CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK scott_remote CONNECT TO scott IDENTIFIED BY tiger USING 'remote_database';

-- Private database link to a user in the local database.

CREATE DATABASE LINK scott_local CONNECT TO scott IDENTIFIED BY tiger
USING 'local';

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/managing-database-links

Comment: Thank you Rakesh for your answer.

Is it possible to create such link on a existing database? I've been searching web for instructions but all I found involved deciding it during Oracle instalation like here:

https://dbaclass.com/article/create-database-link-from-oracle-to-sql-server/